# Move files from one server to another linux with date stamp

Tags: linux, shell

I am attempting to backup my log files from production to a backup location. Both servers are running Linux. I am facing a problem in the destination server when I attempt to put in time stamp:

I have tried this;

```
logpath="/test/MN/PRD/cpp/MNPRD/cdci_logs/MNCDCI/"
backuppath="/test/MN/UAT/cpp/testmove"
time_stamp=$(date +%Y_%m_%d)
scp -r "${logpath}" user@servername:"${backuppath}/${time_stamp}"  
cd "${logpath}"
find . -ctime +1 -type f |xargs rm
```

The files are moved into the other server and a folder with date stamp is created and everything else is dumped there without proper directory structure. I need to Maintain the same directory Structure after the datestamp directory. How Can I achieve this?

**EDIT: I need to have the Last folder name of the Original path in the Destination path e.g:**

```
/test/MN/UAT/cpp/testmove/timestampdir/MNCDCI
```

Comment: Not directly a solution, but have a look at `rsnapshot`. A simple, rsync-based tool for periodical incremental backups over an SSH connection.

Comment: `scp -r` will copy the directory structure, so I'm not sure what you mean by "Maintain the same directory Structure". Can you give an example of the input and output as it currently is and what you would like instead? Please edit your question since formatting gets lost in comments.

Comment: Thank you I meant, is there a way to have the folder MNCDCI under the backup path e.g `/test/MN/UAT/cpp/testmove/datestampdir/MNCDCI` See the edit

Comment: but you have define the destination folder as the original path - did your edit mean logpath 1st line to be retained after timestamp?

Comment: Yes the last Directory on the Logpath i.e `MNCDCI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may come in handy:

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/definedscp/blob/master/elapsed-scp.sh

To do what you are trying do you could try something like this

This is backing up all of the a folder as a tar command then ssh to remote host /tmp inside b folder and extracting it....

```
(cd /tmp/; tar -cvzf - a)|(ssh REMOTE_HOST 'cd /tmp/; tar -xvzf -')
```

Above is where a is a folder in tmp getting directly copied from localhost to remotehost /tmp folder

Edit to add extra stuff you could do to utilise this, not tested but should work.

```
logpath="/test/MN/PRD/cpp/MNPRD/cdci_logs/MNCDCI/"
backuppath="/test/MN/UAT/cpp/testmove"
time_stamp=$(date +%Y_%m_%d)
backup_folder=$backuppath/$time_stamp

    (find $logpath -mtime +1 -exec tar -cvzf - {} \;)|(ssh REMOTE_HOST 'mkdir -p $backup_folder; cd $backup_folder; tar -xvzf -')
```

You could either expand fine to include

```
-name \*somename\* 
-type f/d
```

or expand intial tar to include

```
exclude="something"
exclude="somethingelse"
```

if needs be, but this should then copy files and using tar retain folder structure. Hope it helps